# Create apps using Flutter without Mac and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, flutter, macos

I don't have a **Mac and an iPhone**. How can I make applications using my windows **laptop** for *coding* and without an iPhone for *trying* to run/debug the app? What are the best steps for me??

Notes: I have made several applications for android and web using flutter.

Thanks...

Comment: https://flutter.dev/multi-platform

Comment: you need to use Xcode to build an iOS app and Xcode will only work on macOS. its mean you need a mac. CMIIW

Comment: maybe you can install a macOS on windows 10 with virtual box

Comment: "maybe you can install a macOS on windows 10 with virtual box " not legally.  macos is free if you are running on apple hardware, but prohibited otherwise.  their software -- their rules.

Comment: I just found out that running Mac OS on a virtual machine is illegal...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot build a flutter iOS app directly from Windows. What you can do is use external tools to do it. One of these tools is Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI. It's a tool that let you access remote MacOS build machines.

It's pretty easy to use :

First install it by visiting the website, https://odevio.com/

Then setup your Apple Developer account with Odevio : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

Finally you can build the app and retrieve the IPA in the build section by creating an Ad Hoc build.

And that's it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, please be aware that this requires having an Apple Developer Account which is not free and costs USD 100 per year.

Comment: The apollo website says that the free plan is limited to "One successful publication build every 90 days to release your app on the App Store"